# Getting error when trying to write javascript inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to make a redirection with this javascript function that can display redirection message to the user and redirected to the given URL but I get an error whenever I try to run the php

```
<?php
include 'theme.php';
/*ceklogin();*/
css();
if($_POST['wget-send'])
    {
        $dir=$_POST['dir'];
        $link=$_POST['link'];
        /*exec('cd '.$dir,$out);*/
        exec('echo '.$link.' > /tmp/wget-download-link.txt',$out);
        exec('wget -P '.$dir.' -b -i /tmp/wget-download-link.txt -o /www/wget.log -c -t 100 -w 10',$out);
        echo $out[2];
        echo "
                <script type="text/javascript">   
                function Redirect() 
                    {  
                        window.location="http://www.google.com"; 
                    } 
                document.write("You will be redirected to a new page in 5 seconds"); 
                setTimeout('Redirect()', 5000);   
                </script>
             ";
        exit();
    }
echo "<br><br><form action=wget_log.php method=\"post\">";
echo "Download directory :<br><input type=\"text\" name=\"dir\" size=\"15\" value=\"/mnt/usb/\"/><br>";
echo '<br>Download link :<br>';
echo "<textarea name=\"link\" rows=\"4\" cols=\"35\"></textarea><br><br>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="wget-send" value="Send" />';
echo "</form></div>";

foot();
echo '
</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

The error says:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /www/wget.php on line 14
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The syntax highlighting shows the obvious error

Comment: why do you even need to write javascript using `echo` in php? If you aren't able to even see simple syntax errors that are already highlighted, suggest you don't even try mixing the 2 languages

Comment: This isn't an ideal way to do your templating. Consider writing all your HTML and JavaScript in HTML mode (i.e. outside of PHP tags) and only break into PHP when you need to. See [an example here](https://github.com/halfer/php-tutorial-project/blob/master/edit-post.php).

Answer (score 3):

When you use double quotes inside double quotes you have to *escape* them. That means you put a `\` in front of the inner ones.

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
```

You do the same when putting single quotes inside single:

```
echo '<script type=\'text/javascript\'>';
```

But when mixing them, not necessary. I.e.:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>"; //single inside double
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; //double inside single
```

But really for a long text like your Javascript, you should close the PHP tag and reopen it after. I.e.:

```
<?php
//some php
if(whatever)
{
?>
 <script type="text/javascript"> blah blah blah </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Or better yet, include your Javascript with `<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>` when possible.

Comment: nice support @developerwjk i guess some people like to bully newcomers instead of try to help/guide them